# How do I make the height of a container responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I'm working on a website and I have to make the entire site responsive to desktop, tablet, and mobile. I'm currently working on the tablet section and I made the text size larger so it's easier to read upon a screen, but when I do so it bleeds outside of the respective coloured box it's in. How would I make the height of the box it's in responsive and change to fit the larger text now?

Here's my HTML:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the page at the width of its own screen. -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Visual Resume 2.0</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat+Brush" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/resume2css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <main>
    <header>
    <img src="images/overlay2.png" alt="" width="583px" height="99px" class="overlay floating-block"/>
    </header>


    <section>
    <img src="images/forestedited2.jpg" alt="" width="960px" height="450px" class="forestimg"/>
    <img src="images/bordertop.png" alt="" width="1003" height="82" class="bordertop"/>

    <aside>
    </aside>
    </section>


    <article id="topcontainer">
    <img src="images/profileimage.png" alt="" width="239" height="239" class="profileimg"/>
    <p>
    Donec volutpat, leo vel rhoncus ultrices, quam arcu dictum erat, non interdum eros mi ut elit. Curabitur nec augue quis urna aliquet consequat sit amet non lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur at nunc eget mi pulvinar vestibulum at non ipsum. In eu nibh metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris id turpis a risus malesuada sodales non vel libero. Cras euismod accumsan volutpat. Morbi consectetur, purus sed facilisis auctor, turpis dolor dictum purus, lacinia maximus ex odio non massa. Sed rhoncus, dolor a rhoncus eleifend, quam eros feugiat odio, vel luctus felis ante at leo. Praesent felis ex, venenatis dapibus mauris eu, aliquet tempus eros. Aenean vulputate sodales dui, id lacinia urna pellentesque eget.
    <br>
    <br>
    “The future belongs to a different kind of person with a different kind of mind: artists, inventors, storytellers-creative and holistic ‘right-brain’ thinkers whose abilities mark the fault line between who gets ahead and who doesn’t.” <i><b>–Daniel Pink</b></i>
    </p>

    </article>

    <section2>
    <img src="images/borderbottom.png" alt="" width="1003" height="82" class="borderbottom"/>
    </section2>

    <div class="article">
    <img src="images/title2.png" alt="" width="422" height="41" class="title2"/>

    <h1>PHOTOSHOP</h1>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle2"></div> 
    <h2>ILLUSTRATOR</h2>
    <div class="rectangle3"></div>
    <h3>INDESIGN</h3>
    <div class="rectangle4"></div>
    <div class="rectangle5"></div> 
    <h4>DREAMWEAVER</h4>
    <div class="rectangle6"></div>
    <div class="rectangle7"></div> 

    <img src="images/skill1.png" alt="" width="22" height="41" class="skill1"/>
    <img src="images/skill2.png" alt="" width="22" height="41" class="skill2"/>
    <img src="images/skill3.png" alt="" width="22" height="41" class="skill3"/>

    <p2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec     dui consectetur, sodales tellus vitae, gravida nisl. Nunc vitae aliquet nibh, ac fringilla nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    <br>
    <br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec dui consectetur, sodales tellus vitae, gravida nisl. Nunc vitae aliquet nibh, ac fringilla nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    <br>
    <br>
    Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis.
    </p2>
    </div>

    <img src="images/bordertop2.png" alt="" width="1003" height="82" class="bordertop2"/>

    <section id="section3">
        <video preload controls>
          <source src="FPOmovie.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source src="FPOmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
      </section>

    <img src="images/borderbottom2.png" alt="" width="1003" height="82" class="borderbottom2"/>

    <div class="section4">
    <img src="images/title3.png" alt="" width="192px" height="29px" class="title3"/>
    <img src="images/beerbottles.jpg" alt="" width="482px" height="369px" class="workpiece1"/>
    <img src="images/busad.jpg" alt="" width="393px" height="369px" class="workpiece2"/>
    <img src="images/billboard.jpg" alt="" width="482px" height="362px" class="workpiece3"/>
    <img src="images/totebag2.jpg" alt="" width="393px" height="538px" class="workpiece4"/>

    </div>

    </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* DESKTOP CSS */
/* document */
body{
    margin:0;
    align-content:center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
    }

main{
    width:960px; /* fixed width */
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
/*header*/
.forestimg{
    width:100%;
    }

.overlay{
    float:left;
    margin-top:220px;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
    postion: fixed;
    opacity:50;
    }

.floating-block{
      position: fixed;
    }
/*Biography Section*/
.bordertop{
    float:inherit;
    margin-top:-75px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.borderbottom{
    float:inherit;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    position:relative;
    }   

section2{
    position:relative;
    }
/*Skills Section*/
article{
    margin-top:-10px;
    background-color:#8bcfbd;
    height:315px;
    position:relative;
    }

#topcontainer{
    margin-top:-82px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    height:400px;
    margin-top:25px;
    position:relative;
    }

aside{
    background-color:#8bcfbd;
    height: 170px;
    float:inherit;
    margin-top:-5px;
    padding:0px;
    }

.profileimg{
    float:left;
    margin-left:80px;
    margin-top:30px;
    }

p{
    font-family:Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, "Arial", sans-serif;
    float:right;
    width:510px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-top:45px;
    margin-right:70px;
    }

p2{
    font-family:Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#1f3c48;
    width:510px;
    margin-top:45px;
    margin-right:70px;
    float:right;
    }

 .title2{
    float:right;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-right:270px;
    }

.rectangle{
    width:140px;
    height:10px;
    background:#1f3c48;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 175px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.rectangle2{
    width:32px;
    height:10px;
    background:#8bcfbd;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 283px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.rectangle3{
    width:140px;
    height:10px;
    background:#1f3c48;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 175px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.rectangle4{
    width:140px;
    height:10px;
    background:#1f3c48;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 175px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.rectangle5{
    width:32px;
    height:10px;
    background:#8bcfbd;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 283px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.rectangle6{
    width:140px;
    height:10px;
    background:#1f3c48;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 175px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.rectangle7{
    width:62px;
    height:10px;
    background:#8bcfbd;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 253px;
    position:absolute;
    }

h1{
    font-family:Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#1f3c48;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 128px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    position:absolute;
    }

h2{
    font-family:Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#1f3c48;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 158px;
    margin-bottom: -120px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    position:absolute;
    }

h3{
    font-family:Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#1f3c48;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 188px;
    margin-bottom: -120px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    position:absolute;
    }

h4{
    font-family:Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#1f3c48;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 218px;
    margin-bottom: -120px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.skill1{
    float:right;
    margin-top:121px;
    margin-left:350px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.skill2{
    float:right;
    margin-top:165px;
    margin-left:350px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.skill3{
    float:right;
    margin-top:201px;
    margin-left:350px;
    position:absolute;
    }


/*Video Section*/
#section3{
    background-color:#1f3c48;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    }

.bordertop2{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-80px;
    float:left;
    }


.borderbottom2{
    margin-left:-25px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    }

video {
    width: 99.6%;
    position:relative;
    }

/*Examples of Work Section*/
.section4{
    height:1000px;
    }

.title3{
    float:right;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-right:380px;
    position:relative;
    }

.workpiece1{
    float:left;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-right:-100px;
    position:relative;
    border: 10px solid #1f3c48;
    }

.workpiece2{
    float:left;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:120px;
    position:relative;
    border: 10px solid #1f3c48;
    }

.workpiece3{
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-right:-100px;
    position:relative;
    border: 10px solid #1f3c48;
    }

.workpiece4{
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:120px;
    position:relative;
    border: 10px solid #1f3c48;
    }

/* TABLET CSS */
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 768px) {
    #topcontainer{
        height: auto;
        }

    p{
        font-size:16px;
        }
}
```

Comment: Building responsive means not setting an explicit height, but rather let the content decide how high the element will get.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: just remove the `height` rule...

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work.